# Symfony - extract from short bundle name full path bundle name

Tags: php, symfony

How do I extract the bundle name from its short form to full, for example I want to convert `AcmeDemoBundle` raw string to `Acme\DemoBundle` bundle real namespace

Answer (score 1):

We can get the bundle instance from our kernel by using `getBundle` method, and then user `getNamespace()` method to get the actual namespace of the bundle:

```
$this->container->get('kernel')->getBundle('AcmeDemoBundle')->getNamespace();
// gives me Acme/DemoBundle
```